# Angular Error NG0203 with Firebase and Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[MyCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mKKr.png)

That is my code of a simple angular & firebase project. I didn't had anything else, just checked the link between angular and firestore

[ErrorConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2aFG.png)
This is the error I see from chrome console

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check if you have installed the FireBase SDK?

If not try installing it with `$ npm install --save firebase.`